# AWS Amplify - Can I Push To Code Commit To Start The CI/CD Pipeline & Build The New Backend Resources?

Tags: git, aws-amplify

I understand there is the availability to run `amplify push -y` to deploy any new backend changes to the AWS Amplify env. However, could I instead just use a normal `git push` to deploy the new backend resources?

**Use Case:**

1. `amplify add auth`
2. `git push`
3. CI/CD Pipeline triggers AWS Amplify designated `env` for the Code Commit branch
4. Cognito is built

Is my use case facilitated by this screen grab of enabling "full-stack continuous deployments CI/CD"?

[image: AWS Amplify Screen Grab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Disable automatic builds**
>
> You can configure Amplify to disable automatic builds on every code commit. To set up, choose App settings, General, and then scroll to the Branches section that lists the connected branches. Select a branch, and then choose Action, Disable auto build. Further commits to that branch will no longer trigger a new build.

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html)

This would suggest the screen grab is the correct place to organise automatic backend builds with AWS Amplify upon a `git push`.